# Application not starting on startup

Tags: java, android, boot, permission-denied

I have this in my Manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tominocz.stonequestapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name="com.tominocz.stonequestapp.StartOnBoot"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayerListActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And I have this in my StartOnBoot.java file:

**EDIT:
THIS IS THE ACTUAL StartOnBoot.java FILE I HAVE:**

```
package com.tominocz.stonequestapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import com.tominocz.stonequestapp.config.Config;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public class StartOnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String Latest;
    public static String previous;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            if (new File("/data/data/com.tominocz.stonequestapp/app.properties").exists()) {
                Config.load();

                if (MainActivity.StartOnBoot = true) {
                    getLatestVersion(context);
                    if (MainActivity.EnableNotifications = true) {
                        triggerUpdateNotification(context, "New version " + Latest + " released!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void getLatestVersion(Context ctx) {
        try {
            String myUri = "http://www.stonequest.de/version.php";
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(myUri);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

            String ver = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
            if (ver != null) {
                Latest = ver;
                if (MainActivity.EnableNotifications = true) {
                    if (previous != Latest) {
                        triggerUpdateNotification(ctx, "New version " + Latest + " released!");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public static void loadLastVersion() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/data/data/com.tominocz.stonequestapp/Last.ver"));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            previous = br.readLine();
            fis.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void triggerUpdateNotification(Context ctx, String s) {
        CharSequence title = "StoneQuest just got updated!";
        CharSequence message = s;
        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService("notification");
        Notification notification;
        notification = new Notification(com.tominocz.stonequestapp.R.drawable.ic_launcher, "New version released!",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, null, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, title, message, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(1010, notification);
    }
}
```

I don't know if my app does that, but whenever the android device starts up, a notification saying that the app permissions were denied or something like that will show up..

No matter if it does, or not, the matter is that the app won't start on startup.

I wonder why..

Does anybody know why? Thanks.

Comment: try to replace android.intent.action.MAIN with com.tominocz.stonequestapp.MainActivity and  android.intent.category.LAUNCHER with android.intent.category.DEFAULT, post your logcat for many advice

Comment: Oh wait I think I know what's the problem here..
maybe in the StartOnBoot.java file I should just remove the if statement with scanning for if the system has completed booting..

Comment: The StartOnBoot.java should be normal class file then..
like no extends stuff...

Comment: I didn't post the whole code because the original code isn't for starting the app..

Comment: then put the logcat , and MainActivity extends Acvtivty right? Have you tried to do the replacement that I said?

Comment: read edit, imagine that when config file loads notifications = true and startonboot = true;

Comment: Only once `Activity` can have `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`.

Comment: you may also post the MainActivity code

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tominocz.stonequestapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name="com.tominocz.stonequestapp.StartOnBoot"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tominocz.stonequestapp.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayerListActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tominocz.stonequestapp.PLAYERLISTACTIVITY" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tominocz.stonequestapp.SETTINGSACTIVITY" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Add this to onReceive()

```
  Intent start = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(start);
```

And make sure MainActivity extend Activity